# drilldown report in RDLC and asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

was posed with a question to look for possibilities whether ASP.Net MVC and  rdlc can offer drilldown reports (the backend database is MySQL) .

as per personal understanding , have found it difficult since back in mind, the main concern is that rdlc in MVC simply returns a flat pdf (or at least to  the extent am aware).

any guidance / help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you will not be able to use Microsoft ReportViewer control for any on-screen interactive rendering of RDLC reports because it is only compatible with WebForms for on-screen rendering.

For MVC I recommend using RDL reports (server-based) instead (also for this reason: [RDLC Performance Issues in .NET 4.5](http://travis.io/blog/2014/10/27/rdlc-performance-issues-dotnet45/)) and you will need to make your own UI to render them. This control can be useful: [MvcReportViewer](https://github.com/alanjuden?tab=repositories) as it allows you to receive HTML-formatted report page and use it in your MVC application.

Comment: thank you for the answer. will look into the matter and respond back asap.

Comment: Alternatively you can render these reports in a separate .Net 3.5 web application and display them in iframe (this approach is described in Performance Issues page I linked to)